# Azure Function / Azure Service Bus: Manually completing a message

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I'd like to mark a message as complete after successful completion of all activities. In this case `autoCompleteMessages` is set to `false` in `host.json`.

I can complete or dead letter a message from the `ServiceBusTrigger` function, but how do I ensure all activities succeeded?

Can it be done in the `OrchestrationTrigger` function?

```cs
FunctionName("QueueStart")]
public static async Task Run(
    [ServiceBusTrigger("%QueueTopicName%", "Subscription", Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString")]
    ServiceBusReceivedMessage msg,
    ServiceBusMessageActions messageActions,
    [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient starter,
    ILogger log)
{

    string inputMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(msg.Body);
    
    await starter.StartNewAsync("Hello", null, inputMessage);

    // can run here, but how to check if all activities succeeded?
    // await messageActions.CompleteMessageAsync(msg);
    // await messageActions.DeadLetterMessageAsync(msg);

}

[FunctionName("Hello")]
public static async Task<List<string>> RunOrchestrator(
    [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context, ILogger log)
{
    var outputs = new List<string>();

    outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>("Hello_Hello", "London"));
    outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>("Hello_Hello1", "Seattle"));

    // how to mark message as complete here?

    return outputs;
}

[FunctionName("Hello_Hello")]
public static string SayHello([ActivityTrigger] string name, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"Saying hello to {name}.");
    return $"Hello {name}!";
}

[FunctionName("Hello_Hello1")]
public static string SayHello1([ActivityTrigger] string city, ILogger log)
{
    throw new Exception("Exception from hello1");

    log.LogInformation($"Saying hello1 to {city}.");
    return $"Hello {city}!";
}
```

Comment: Message completion must be performed on the same AMQP link that the message was received from.  In this case, that connection and link are owned by the `ServiceBusTrigger`.   You would need a way to hold a reference to the exact `ServiceBusMessageActions` and `ServiceBusReceivedMessage` that the trigger populated in your orchestration context - and you'd have to complete the entire end-to-end flow before the message lock expired.  I don't have the insight to comment on how to verify all activities succeeded, but that may be the better path.

Comment: yes from what I've read, the completion must be done in the `ServiceBusTrigger` and can not be done in the `OrchestrationTrigger`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following included in the `ServiceBusTrigger` does the trick

```cs
string instanceID = Guid.NewGuid();
await starter.StartNewAsync("Hello", instanceID, inputMessage);

var orchestratorStatus = await starter.GetStatusAsync(instanceID);

while (orchestratorStatus.RuntimeStatus == OrchestrationRuntimeStatus.Running || orchestratorStatus.RuntimeStatus == OrchestrationRuntimeStatus.Pending)
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    orchestratorStatus = await starter.GetStatusAsync(instanceID);
}

if (orchestratorStatus.RuntimeStatus == OrchestrationRuntimeStatus.Completed)
{
    logger.LogInformation($"Completed orchestration with ID = '{instanceID}'.");
    await messageActions.CompleteMessageAsync(msg);
}
```