# Azure function app, service buss trigger, how to explicitly confirm message

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

What is the best/correct was to explicitly confirm a message using an Azure function app that has a service bus trigger? I'd like to confirm the message only when it's successful or if there is an error due to the data, but not confirm is certain other issues appear -- so the app will pull the message again.

Here is what I have. I see how to set the app to AutoComplete=false, and how to get the MessageReceiver object, but not how to confirm the messages, since right now I'm receiving the messages as an array of strings.

This is the doc I'm trying to understand: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.core.messagereceiver?view=azure-dotnet

Also, I'm processing these in batches, so if something goes wrong with the batch, I'd rather just not confirm and pull them on the next run. This is a simplified example.

In the below example, when I add ServiceBusReceiver I get the following runtime error.

> Cannot bind parameter 'serviceBusReceiver' to type ServiceBusReceiver. Make sure the parameter Type is supported by the binding. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. Azure Storage, ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. builder.AddAzureStorage(), builder.AddServiceBus(), builder.AddTimers(), etc.).

When I add ServiceBusMessageActions Visual Studio can't find the class.

```
[FunctionName("ProcessUserProfile")]
public async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("events.userprofile", Connection = "AzureWebJobsServiceBus", AutoComplete = false)] 
    ServiceBusReceivedMessage [] myQueueItems,
    //ServiceBusMessageActions serviceBusMessageActions, // Isn't found
    ServiceBusReceiver serviceBusReceiver, // Gives a runtime error, 
    ILogger log)
{
    if (fancyBusiness(myQueueItems) {
        foreach (ServiceBusReceivedMessage item in myQueueItems)
        {
            // Confirm
            await serviceBusReceiver.CompleteMessageAsync(item);
        }
    }
    else {
        // Don't confirm
    }           
}
```

Comment: I think this answers your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72717865/azure-function-azure-service-bus-manually-completing-a-message

Comment: This one is also helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72717865/azure-function-azure-service-bus-manually-completing-a-message  But it looks like both are using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus. But how do I do this similarly with Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus?view=azure-dotnet

Comment: Does the MessageReceiver have a method .CompleteAsync() .  You might have to add ServiceBusMessageReceived to your function.  Sorry I don't have an example handy.  Maybe this helps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp

Comment: I updated my op with my progress. The examples I find use ServiceBusMessageActions, which doesn't seem to be included in Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus 7.11.1. I'm also trying to use ServiceBusReceiver, which has a method called CompleteMessageAsync, which looks like what I need, but it give the runtime error I describe above.

Comment: I think I have this figured out now. It comes down to old versions of the Webjob library. I'll add a clean example once I get my ducks in a row.